Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:3 missing EOF at 'WITH' near '"This is a DPCI_LIST table"'
CREATE TABLE XX.DPCI_LIST_FY17 
(
    DPCI varchar(100) COMMENT 'DPCI_description'
) 
COMMENT "This is a DPCI_LIST table"
WITH (
   external_location = 'hdfs://bigred3ns//user/XX/DPCI_Desc'
     format = 'TEXTFILE',
  textfile_field_separator = ','
);

Can you please help me with this error I get?

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:3 missing EOF at 'WITH' near '"This is a DPCI_LIST table"'

I am trying to create a table and insert contents from the path listed... not able to do so

That doesn't look anything like valid DDL for hive:  documentation
